# Invoking a XIB from a HTML page in Phonegap

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios4

I am writing an app using PhoneGap framework. The main screen has four buttons and if I click the first button, a native app that has been written to show a Map in MapKit should execute. How to invoke this app from a javascript call?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to write a plugin for that feature.

For calling a external .xib you can look at some of the code from the [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/0973ed1712a8f705576401e13e43f571b831397a/iPhone/ChildBrowser).

There is also a [MapKit plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/0973ed1712a8f705576401e13e43f571b831397a/iPhone/MapKitPlug) available:

Comment: No problem. I self have some experience in Phonegap, but I prefer developing native apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the plugin architecture of phonegap.

Here is the wiki entry for writing phonegap plugins for iOs: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS